# How to change the date and time of my computer device, using protractor

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, protractor, end-to-end

I need to test whether announcements are expired or not after 6 months. Currently I am successfully testing that announcement is correct or not.

After 6 months it must be removed from a particular tab. The problem is: How can I simulate a system time 6 months in the future with protractor?

Comment: I don't think that changing system time is a good approach. You can rather create 'announcement' in the past date(6 months back). Then as the time completes, you can check if the announcement expires!

Comment: Thanks @SakshiSingla, i knew, but i need a flow in this test. as per you opinion, if we create an announcement in the past date(6 months back), it's directly expires now, but my specification is i want to check announcement is announce or not, in between creation and expire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about it differently.

Mock the HTTP response that your app sends containing announcements and set the desired date using [`protractor-http-mock`](https://github.com/atecarlos/protractor-http-mock) library. In other words, let the frontend think there is an expired announcement.

---

Alternative options would include mocking the time with the help of [`Sinon.js`](http://sinonjs.org/) or [`TimeShift.js`](https://github.com/plaa/TimeShift-js), but, personally, I think that involving these tools would be an overcomplication. Anyway, see:

- [Faking system time/date with Selenium Webdriver?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8838/faking-system-time-date-with-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

If you do have a legitimate need to manipulate the browsers datetime while under test using protractor, I put together A writeup here : [How to change the browser date in protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46679972/how-to-change-the-browser-date-in-protractor/46679973#46679973).

I agree that you should think twice before using this approach as mocking responses will get what you want most of the time

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this with the help of node-windows..
Install node-windows using the command npm i node-windows first..

Code:

```
   const win = require('node-windows')
   const sys = require('util')
    let dateTime    = new Date("10-10-2007) //Convert string or number to date
    let day     = dateTime.getDate() 
    let month   = dateTime.getUTCMonth() + 1 
    let year    = dateTime.getFullYear() 
    let updateD = `${month}-${day}-${year}` //Format the string correctly according to thesystme format
    console.log(updateD)
    //Add a callback function (this can be somewhere else)
    function execCallback(error, stdout, stderr) { 
         if (error) {
             console.log(error)
         } else {
             console.log(stdout) 
         }
    }
    console.log(" execute in command prompt now")

    var exec = win.elevate(`cmd /c date ${updateD}`,undefined, execCallback);

    console.log(" execution completed ")
```