# How to (temporarily) override Object.prototype.toString or any other JS native code

Tags: javascript

In JS in a modern browser context (Chrome specifically but any answer is interesting) how do I temporarily override `Object.prototype.toString` or any other native code method such that the new implementation will actually receive values passed to it when invoked via `call` ?

This is the obvious/intuitive approach (run in the browser dev tools panel), and it does not work:

```
console.log(Object.prototype.toString)
// (output) > ƒ toString() { [native code] }

Object.prototype.toString.call(new Date())
// (output) > "[object Date]"

Object.prototype.toString = function (value) {
  console.log(`value is ${value}`)
  return 'foo'
}

Object.prototype.toString.call(new Date())
// (output) > value is undefined
// (output) > "foo"
```

Two questions:

1. why is the `value` in the above undefined ?
2. is there a way to override/monkey patch `Object.prototype.toString` so that function arguments will be passed to the new implementation ?

You can stop reading here without missing anything relevant to the questions above

---

*Background / Context*

Surely there will be some "why would you ever do this" responses. The context is a Selenium/Protractor based production verification suite, operating on top of real APIs (no mock data), where the suite has a need to advance browser time by one month so that certain UI operations become available.

I recently found that any solution that [replaces the Date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46679972/how-to-change-the-browser-date-in-protractor/) will not work with Angular 1.x because Angular has a `isDate` method that calls - you guessed it - `Object.prototype.toString.call(dateCandidate)` and if that does not return the exact string `[object Date]` then any Angular Date formatting code will not work.

Angular code in question:

- isDate implementation : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.11/src/Angular.js#L593
- Angular dateFilter that will break on mocked Date object: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.11/src/ng/filter/filters.js#L621

Angular discussing why they will not change the behaviour : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7143

Which leaves me with several bad options. This question is advancing the 'why dont we make a one line patch to Angular and then on demand override the `Object.prototype.toString` implementation to return `[Object Date]` on our timeshift-js mock Date object' option, which is the current front runner amongst our list of bad solutions.

Comment: Calling a method, or invoking it with `.call` on an object, sets the `this` keyword. It doesn't pass a `value` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you input the wrong parameter, the first parameter of `call`, `bind`, `apply` is the `context`, not the called function's params

this code:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(new Date())
// (output) > value is undefined
// (output) > "foo"
```

should be:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(this, 'Bar')
// (output) > value is Bar
// (output) > "foo"
// this one also valid because you don't care about context
Object.prototype.toString.call(null, 'Bar')
```

The native `.toString` doesn't have any parameters because it's used to parsing the `Object` that trigger it to String. For example, if I want to do the same with the native one, I'll modify the `toString` like this;

```
Object.prototype.toString = function() { 
    return JSON.stringify(this);
}
var a = { foo : 'bar'}
Object.prototype.toString.call(a);
 // or
a.toString()
// has the same output:
// "{"foo":"bar"}"
```

Comment: Hi @Kai, you are right. But what gets me is that is not how the angular implementation is invoking the function, but it is working for them ...

they start by creating a local copy of `Object.prototype.toString`:
`var toString  = Object.prototype.toString` then in the `isDate` implementation: `function isDate(value) {  return toString.call(value) === '[object Date]';  }`

so does it work for them because they are calling a local reference to the function ?

Comment: But...isn't `.toString()` typically called without any arguments? Why would you say `.call(this, ...)` when trying to get the `.toString()` of a date value?

Comment: I look at your example that receives an argument `value` then displays it on console.log, so I thought you want to modify `.toString` to receive a `value` and display it.
`.toString()` is called without arguments, it will use the context of the object call it to display data. Eg: `var a = { a : 1}, a.toString()` it mean that you want to do `toString()` with data from object `a`. I update the answer to make show you my idea

Comment: It is important to note that the code in question is calling the Object prototype `toString` directly, which is meant to detect the type of class , as documented here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString under the heading "Using toString() to detect object class" . That is the behaviour I need to modify while under test, so that Angular's `isDate(x)` returns true when x is in fact a mock Date object (implemented by npm timeshift-js or similar library)

Comment: @zayquan, may I know what type of `x`? is it a `new Date()` object? And you want to detect it is Date object or not, don't you?
if yes, I think you can check yourself by `isDate = function (val) { return val instanceof Date};` ( no need angular's isDate())

Comment: @kai your last update cleared everything up thanks for the quick answer and follow up! In the case I was struggling with, x was `new TimeShift.Date()` where TImeShift is coming from [https://www.npmjs.com/package/timeshift-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/timeshift-js)